# Reload video if src file changes on server to another video with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

How to reload video on page if I change src file on disk?

For example, I have

```
<video controls="controls" id="myVideo">
    <source id="source" src="~/videos/Intro.mp4" type=video/mp4 />
</video>
```

On disk I replace file Intro.mp4 to another video with same name.
If I use $("#myVideo").load() , it happens nothing. When I refresh page, in Opera my video does not changes, in Edge it reloads. I need to reload video without refresh page.

UPD: In some reasons I cannot use files with different names, I need to use only Intro.mp4 name

Comment: What was your solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only changing the file and keeping the same file name it is very likely that the browser is caching the old video. If you want to change the video without reloading you will need both videos on the disk in the same location. `~/videos/Intro1.mp4` and `~/videos/Intro2.mp4` for example.

The you can change the source of the video using JQuery.

`$('#myVideo source').attr('src', '~/videos/Intro2.mp4');`

Once the source is changed you can run `$("#myVideo")[0].load();` to change the video playing without reloading the page.

Comment: In some reasons I cannot use files with different names, I need to use only Intro.mp4 name

Comment: This isn't going to be possible then, especially for a public page. How do you plan to change the file when other people view the page? How will you know when they are on the site?

Answer (score 0):

I am reloading the video on error. When the replacing takes place, and i change the frame of the video an error occurs (e.g. `Error 3; details: PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: VDA Error 4`), so this is when i reload the video.

```
var video = $('#myVideo')[0];
var hadError = false;
video.onerror = function () {
  console.log('Error ' + video.error.code + '; details: ' + video.error.message);
  hadError = true;
  video.load();
};
video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
  if(hadError) { video.onerror = null; }
});
```